# How to create one vertical column in between rows in Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

Is there is a way to create this style with Flexbox?

Comment: Could you please provide the code block? It will help in understanding what you have done so far.

Comment: the size of those boxes is fixed? Should they be responsive? Some of the boxes may be missing?

Comment: I didn't try it so far because I don't have an idea how to start it. If I do flex direction to row how to align one column in between like that.

Comment: **No, this is not possible with flexbox**

Comment: Size is fixed yes, on mobile version I am going to remove the big column and make the flex direction column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this. Either flexbox or CSS grid, both are good, but I prefer the CSS grid way:

**Flexbox**

```css
.container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 90%;
        width: 30%;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: gray;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 30%;
    }

    .box1 {
        height: 30%;
    }
    
    .box2, .box5 {
        height: 30%;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .middle {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .column-large {
        margin: 0 20px;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box box1">1</div>
        <div class="box box2">2</div>
        <div class="box box3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-large">
        <div class="box middle">middle</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box box4">4</div>
        <div class="box box5">5</div>
        <div class="box box6">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Grid**

With CSS grid, this is what you can achieve. If you play around with the widths and heights, you could fit this to your needs. In case you want to know more about CSS grid in general, this article is a very good way to start: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/.

```css
.container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            ". middle ."
            "tl middle tr"
            "ml middle mr"
            "bl middle br"
            ". middle .";
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 5% 30% 30% 30% 5%;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: gray;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .box1 {
        grid-area: tl;
    }
    
    .box2 {
        grid-area: tr;
    }
    .box3 {
        grid-area: ml;
    }
    .box4 {
        grid-area: mr;
    }
    .box5 {
        grid-area: bl;
    }
    .box6 {
        grid-area: br;
    }
    .middle {
        grid-area: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box middle">middle</div>
</div>
```